# Why does the service worker suddenly fail to cache pages after 3 items

Tags: service-worker

i am currently working on an online paint program that can run offline, but for some reason, after cache 3 pages, it suddenly decides that it doesn't want to cache anymore. can some one please help me? ( the page is [located here](https://paintx.elburg.repl.co/).

[the logs of the service worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wgMJ.png)

Comment: Please, make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise returned by [`cache.addAll()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dom-cache-addall) will reject if any of the responses for the URLs you pass in do not have an "[OK status](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status)".

If you take a look at the Network panel in Chrome's DevTools, you'll see that the response code for one of the URLs you pass in, `/icns/pwa.png`, is `404`. That's because the URL doesn't exist on your server.

[image: network panel]

You can fix this by either removing `/icns/pwa.png` from the list of URL you pass to `cache.addAll()`, or uploading a valid file to your server so that you'll get back a HTTP 200 response for that URL.

Comment: I renamed the file and now it works. thanks.